# Where to add social sharing code from provided jsfiddle to fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, fancybox

This is a very, very basic questions, as I'm brand new to Javascript and Jquery, but I can't seem to find the answer anywhere.

I'm attempting to implement FancyBox on one page on our website, including the additional social sharing buttons provided by the FancyBox Tips and Tricks.

Here's what I've got to so far (no social sharing yet), and I like it:
http://www.aatg.org/default.asp?page=Testpageja

The issue is I can't figure out where to add the code for the social sharing buttons to the jquery.fancybox.js file provided. I'm simply too new to be able to figure out where the function should be. I've got it figured out in JSFiddle so that it works, I just don't know where to put it now on my website so it functions.

Here's what I've come up with in JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/G5TC3/3186/

```
$(".fancybox")
.attr('rel', 'gallery')
.fancybox({
    beforeShow: function () {
        if (this.title) {
            // New line
            this.title += '<br />';

            // Add tweet button
            this.title += '<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-count="none" data-url="' + this.href + '">Tweet</a> ';

            // Add FaceBook like button
            this.title += '<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/share_button.php?href=' + this.href + '&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=true&amp;width=500&amp;action=like&amp;font&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=23" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:110px; height:23px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>';
        }
    },
    afterShow: function() {
        // Render tweet button
        twttr.widgets.load();
    },
    helpers : {
        title : {
            type: 'inside'
        }
    }  
});
```

`

Can anyone help tell me where this needs to go in the jquery.fancybox.js file (downloadable from Fancybox). Maybe I've got that wrong and the above code needs to go into jquery.fancybox.pack.js?
(Note: It's now a FB share not a like button, but that's what I want).

Thanks so much in advance for helping a noob out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the page you provided, you initialize fancybox on line 469:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox();
  });
</script>
```

so you could just replace the line `$(".fancybox").fancybox();` with the script from the Fiddle and it should work.
Basically, you wouldn't add the code to intialize a plugin to the plugin files itself, but either add it as inline script in your HTML (as you already did) or add it in a separate script-file that you include in your page which can be better for maintainability.

Note that your page is not valid HTML - you have two additional `head` and `body` tags that you should remove - the second `head` tag is in line 446:

```
<div id="CustomPageBody"><head>
```

and closes in line 452. The second `body` tag is line 454 and closes in line 464 below the script that initializes fancybox.

Comment: Thanks so, so  much! I definitely overlooked that place--I did exactly as you asked and unfortunately the pics are loading now as if fancyBox is not being called at all, the image is just loading in the page.

Comment: @user2697568 I've just checked your updated page - you're missing the closing `});` for the `$(document).ready(function() {`. Note that currently you have 2 script errors  - `SyntaxError: missing } after function body` for line 479 where you should add this `});`. The 2nd error - `TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function` might be related, but add the missing brackets for fancybox first.

Comment: Thanks so much Matthias! I just changed it, and it's fixed! Looks like the twitter widget image isn't loading, but that's something I can figure out on my own. You helped me so much, thank you!

Comment: @user2697568 Glad I was able to help you :) . If this answered your question, you can accept this answer so the question will be marked as closed / solved. In case you don't know how this works and why, just check http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#answer-5235

Comment: Thanks for the tip, got that taken care of, @matthias_h!